# Incompatiblity between pdfcomment options and MNRAS sections

Tags: pdfcomment

The following minimal example does not compile:

```
\documentclass{mnras}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\section{\pdfcomment[color={1.0 0 0}]{title}}
\end{document}
```

That is, `pdflatex` shows the following error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `COLOR' undefined in families `pdfcomment'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
```

Considering that MNRAS makes all text inside of the `\section` uppercase, I assume this is the source of the problem, i.e. the section macro parses the text and makes it uppercase before it gets parsed by pdfcomment.

Is there any way to get around this without redefining `\section` (or some related macro)?

For reference, I'm using TeXLive `2020.20210202-3` on Debian Unstable.

Comment: I am not entirely convinced it is a good idea to put a pdf annotation inside the `\section`. I don't know about the MNRAS class, but sometimes the section title is also used in the table of contents and the header of the resulting document. Can you say what you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the comment in a command that you define first:

```
\documentclass{mnras}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\def\seccomment{\pdfcomment[color={1.0 0 0}]{title}}
\section{\seccomment}
abc
\section{regular section}
def
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this won't work well in the bookmarks, better use \section[title]{\pdfcomment ...}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that gives the same error as in the question.

Comment: yes, you are right, combine both ideas: use the optional argument and the command.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without "polluting" the preamble (i.e. namespace) with `def`s? My current workaround is to put `\usepackage[color={1.0 0 0}]{pdfcomment}`, and call `\pdfcomment` without options, which then compiles successfully. Unfortunately, then the text inside the comment becomes uppercase, so it's only a partial fix.

Comment: @JCGoran I imagine that in your real document you have both an actual title and a comment, and the title should stay in upper case while the comment should be left as it is - so `\section{a title\pdfcomment{comment about the title}}`, for which the first `a title` should be uppercased. Is that correct? If yes then it is a bit tricky, because the uppercasing should be switched off only partially.

Comment: @Marijn in principle, the title could be written in normal case, as long as the stuff in `\pdfcomment` is left as-is, does that simplify the situation somewhat?